# ObjectInputStream with clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap

Tags: java, serialization, clojure

I have a strange problem.

1. If I take a clojure map of type String, Long
2. serialize it using `java.io.ObjectInputStream` using Clojure 1.6.0
3. deserialize it using `java.io.ObjectInputStream` using Clojure 1.5.1

I can print the new map in the repl, get all values using `vals`, get all keys using `keys` however I cannot get a value using `get`.

`(get new-map "stringkey") => nil`

However, `into {}` fixes things.

I appreciate it's probably not a great idea switching versions while using Java serialization and I can indeed fix the problem however I am now interested in why it happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure's hashing code was changed with 1.6, and `get` relies on the hashes of the keys being looked up.